# Values with special chars blank in dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I have moved my PHP websites to another host, with newer PHP version, Apache version, etc.

I have copied my files from my old host to the new host. The only thing I have changed after that copy is changing `mssql_query` to `db_query`, and the additional libraries installed to use this command.

I now experience the problem my dropdown values on the website that contains the characters, for example: `é` or `ë`, are now blank records.

This worked before the move, any idea what I can check for this problem?

Edit:

Does it has anything to do with the new connection via ODBC? Is it possible to set the charset in this connection?

```
    function db_connect($server, $username, $password, $database, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    $$link = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=".$server.";Database=".$database.";", $username, $password);
    return $$link;
  }

  function db_close($link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    return odbc_close($$link);
  }
```

Comment: Are those special chars escaped?

Comment: Have you tried to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before display them ?

Comment: check your settings for utf-8 in database , database connection , php , html

Comment: Yes, I think it has to something with the connection, the php & html pages are looking fine, also because they did work with the old connection.

Comment: Your question mentions `mssql_query` (SQL Server) and `db_query` (which isn't a standard PHP function). Your question is _tagged_ with [tag:mysql]. What database engine are you really using? What is the actual code you are using if it isn't `db_query`?

Comment: Chris, i was using mssql_query before and have changed it to db_query (so installed this additional function), after that the issue with the blank records came up.

Answer (score 0):

first use it in your main html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

or in your php file just use it

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

if it is not work then use

```
<?php
 $string = htmlentities("Your text");
?>
```

then show it. i think it will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have this available in my pages, I have edited my post with some connection information, I think I have to search the problem there.